# BoxInsetLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I created sample android wear activity project in android studio v1.2.2. I deleted WatchViewStub and used [this example](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html#same-layout) to create activity with BoxInsetLayout. But BoxInsetLayout doesn't work correctly on Round Device. And I tested this on moto 360 android 5.1.1 and before update on moto 360 version 5.0.1. And I tested this on emulator. And It doesn't work at all. All time I see  this:

[image]

but must be this

[image]

My code below:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_box="all">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello Android Wear"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_ok"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Why doesn't it work? Where did I mistake? And How can I use correctly BoxInsetLayout on devices with Round screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in your activity_main.xml, where you specified:

```
android:padding="15dp"
```

If you remove this, then it should work. BoxInsetLayout uses padding in the implementation, and you have changed the value which gives the incorrect output you observed.

(edit)
It is important to note that BoxInsetLayout adjusts the padding in both itself, and also the child views. So make sure you do not change the padding values or things will break. You can try embedding a second FrameLayout if you want to have more control over the padding.

Comment: Thank you for support! Maybe you know why also padding doesn't work in FrameLayout?

Comment: This is not working for me at all. I've copypasted this xml in my project but still get the same result without insets.

Comment: Thanks. But on http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html#same-layout the documentation explains why `BoxInsetLayout` needs a 15dp padding. Google needs to correct the guide

Answer (score 2):

I removed
`android:padding="15dp`"
from BoxInsetLayout as [**Wayne Piekarski**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328415/2112688) said. Now BoxInsetLayout works correctly, but I got a new problem: `android:padding="5dp"`  in FrameLayout doesn't work. I experimented with activity_layout and I added id and changed **padding** to **20dp** and I got this result for Round and Square screen:

[image: Square screen][image: Round Screen]

My xml code for this

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_box="all">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello Android Wear"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_ok" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_cancel" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

So, padding doesn't work in FrameLayout with id *first_frame_layout*. 
But in official documentation You can read about `android:padding="5dp"` in FrameLayout

> This line assigns padding to the inner FrameLayout element. This
>   padding applies to both square and round screens. The total padding
>   between the buttons and the window insets is 20 dp on square screens
>   (15+5) and 5 dp on round screens.

**To quick fix this problem:** I added new FrameLayout with id *second_frame_layout* as a child to FrameLayout with id *first_frame_layout*. I deleted padding from *first_frame_layout* and added `padding="5dp"` to *second_frame_layout*. I got this result:

[image: Good Square screen][image: Good Round screen]

**final activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_box="all">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello Android Wear"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_ok" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_cancel" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Now. It works the way I want on Square and Round screens.

Comment: BoxInsetLayout uses tricks with padding in both itself, and the child. You should not change these padding values or things break, as you have seen. The best way I've seen to work around these issues is to embed a second FrameLayout like you suggested here, and adjust the padding of that.

Comment: @WaynePiekarski is [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html#same-layout), mentioned in the question,  just wildly out of date then?

Comment: Or alternatively, is this failure to properly handle padding a recent regression?