# BoxInsetLayout on Android wearable round screen not working with Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, material-design, wear-os, android-appcompat, android-theme

I'm developing an app for `Android` wearables. I want to create a layout working on both round and square screens. Therefore I'm using `BoxInsetLayout`.

I also want to use a `CheckBox` from `Material Theme`. Therefore I'm using a custom theme derived from `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

The problem is that `BoxInsetLayout` is not working properly on round screens. I'm having the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208891/) but the solution mentioned there is not working for me. The relevant code parts are the same except the theming part.

When I switch the theme to `Theme.DeviceDefault` I only get the `CheckBox` from `Holo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
<item name="android:windowOverscan">true</item>
```

to your theme. It is necessary for dispatching insets.